Как разблокировать Discord?
Какой клиент VPN умеет раздельное туннелирование для отдельных программ (хочу арендовать виртуальный сервер и на нём поднять VPN)? Чтоб весь трафик приложения шёл через VPN тоннель, а всё остальное через основную сеть. (Windows, Россия, Discord)
Пробовали amneziavpn, goodbyedpi, purevpn (не работает)

Сходи на https://habr.com/ru/feed/ - там эту тему мусолят уже не первый день.
